# What is the best method for strong timber wall inside tin shed

Tags: shed, timber-framing

I have a tin shed in the yard approximately 3m x 4m. It has a concrete base.

The walls are tin and the verticals/studs are very far between and not super solid.

I want to build a french cleat system against one wall, however the tin is not suitable to mount to.

Would the best solution be to build a new timber stud wall against one of the tin walls, dynabolted onto the concrete?

How far out would I need to brace perpendicular to the wall to allow it to carry the load of french cleat system, and all the things I want to eventually hang off it? ie. Power tools, clamps, shelves, storage boxes.

[image]

Comment: FYI, your shed is almost certainly steel, and not tin. Timber, where I am, usually means large, rough-sawn posts and planks like you'd see in an old barn. Are you using that, or modern lumber? For bracing, are you thinking of diagonals at the ends, or what? A sketch would be great.

Comment: Hi @isherwood modern lumber.  It's pretty commonly referred to as timber over here.

I was considering diagonal bracing, running to a horizontal plate.  I'll put together a sketch and update.

Comment: @isherwood here's the sketch of what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sketch is more or less what I pictured. I'd make a few adjustments:

1. The primary stress will be at the points where the diagonals connect to the end studs. The entire horizontal load vector of the wall's contents is supported there. I'd double the end studs.
2. Bring those connections up to at least half the wall height. I'd even go to 2/3 to reduce the bending load on the end studs.
3. The top plate has to carry the horizontal load of the center portion of the wall's contents outward to the end studs. I'd double that, too. Maybe consider a 2x6 or 2x8 up there for stiffness.

That's really it. As long as the bottom ends of the diagonals are slightly further from the wall than the center of gravity of the wall's contents, you should be dandy. Don't go crazy mounting it all to the floor. Friction will do most of the work.